# QT Creator CMake no C compiler path set

Tags: c, cmake, qt-creator

I am running into the following issue when I try to select a kit in QT Creator:

CMake configuration has no path to a c compiler set, even though the kit has a valid tool chain.

This is preventing me from running my project. Does anyone know what the solution is?

Answer (score 1):

First of: Does your CMake project actually contain C files at all?

If not: You can disable C support for your cmake project then by defining a C++-only project in the PROJECT line of your CMakeLists.txt file (just add "LANGUAGES CXX"). This saves a tiny bit of time each time you run cmake on your project.

With this micro-optimization out of the way:

Check in Tools>Options>Kits. Does the kit in question list a C compiler?

No C compiler is listed in the kit: Go to the toolchain tab. Are there C compilers listed there? Add some if not:-) Then "Apply" and go back to the kits and add a C compiler.

A C compiler is listed in the kit: Does CMake also know about it? Check the "CMake Configuration" field of the kit. Does it list a CMAKE_C_COMPILER there? It should.

If it does not: Add that information yourself. You can also add anything CMake definitions you want there -- they will be applied to all projects you create from that point on using the kit.

I hope this helps:-)